# BTSTask Add Non-BizTalk dll to Application

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

Is there a way to use BTSTask to add a non dll assembly to a BizTalk application? If I use the "AddReference" command it seems like it only allows you to add BizTalk assemblies?

Comment: By non-dll assembly do you mean an .exe?

Comment: No, I mean a C# or other type of assembly that doesn't contain BizTalk artifacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can add any .NET assembly as resource and package it in the MSI.  See this topic http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561819(BTS.70).aspx